# ajax json post request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post

This may be a really simple problem, I am just way out of my element here...

I have this function `GetData()`, which is copied and pasted from a working example, that sends a `POST` request to a server generating a `JSON` object with random data for CPU, Disk, and CPU Core

```
function GetData() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/AjaxUpdateChart.aspx",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: update,
        error: function () {
            document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += "error" +"<br />";
            setTimeout(GetData, updateInterval);
        }
    });
}
```

However it always receives an error and never goes to success. I can use `POSTMAN` to post to this URL and I will receive a valid JSON object. I've included all of the applicable libraries. I don't understand what's going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: I'll bet you're running into the AJAX same-origin restriction.

Comment: the code I have doesn't actually return any errors, I was just trying to debug it and updating innerHTML to try to figure out where it was getting hung up.

I'm running this on a raspberry pi if that does anything for you...the pi is what's actually serving up the page and I'm trying to post to the server that was used in this working example

http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/how-to-make-jquery-flot-ajax-update-chart.html

Comment: Barmar is correct. you cannot make cross origin requests in javascript. So unless your code is running on that domain, you will not be able to request data from it with XHR. Postman does not have that restriction.